# Click counter, different events per click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am seeking to create an array that counts and keep tracks of clicks done to a certain area of the page; I would then like each amount of click to do something. Eg.) The 5th click a sound via mp3 triggers. The sixth click the page shakes.

How could I write an array to add different events per a number of clicks, assigning something to a specific number of clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/izutav/1/edit

By simply creating an array of your events functions:

```
var a1_Events = [shake, noise, something],
    a1_c = 0;


function shake(){
  alert('SHAKING!');
}

function noise(){
  alert('BZZZZZZZZZZZ!');
}

function something(){
  alert('SOMETHING ELSE!');
}


$('#area1').click(function(){
   a1_Events[a1_c++ % a1_Events.length]();
});
```

If you don't want to loop your events than use just: `a1_Events[a1_c++]();`

Answer (score 2):

```
var clicks = 0;
$('a').click(function() {
    switch(++clicks) {
        case X:
            /* do something */
            break;
       /* ... */
    }
});
```

Or you can store functions in array

```
var myEvents = [function1, function2, function3];
var clicks = -1;
$('a').click(function() {
    clicks++;
    if(myEvents[clicks] != undefined) myEvents[clicks]();
});
```

Comment: First solution is really elegant! +1

Comment: I am also confused regarding the 'break;' I have not seen this before. So, I could add a new function; right above that line, right? And the next set of code just stores and calls those functions; right? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @1977 - `break` is part of `switch/case` ... its javascript basics

Answer (score 1):

Something like this!

```
var actions = {
  5: 'playMusic',
  6: 'shakeDiv'     
}, 
actors = {
 doNothing: function() {/*default action; do nothing;*/},
 playMusic: function() {
     alert('Your are about to here a music now');
     /*place code for playing music here*/
   },
 shakeDiv: function() {
    alert('page is about to shake');
    /* place shake animation code here*/
  }
},
defaultActionName = 'doNothing';//default action name


var clickCount = 0;

$('yourSelectorForThepart').click(function(e) {
  clickCount++;
  doAction();
});

function doAction() {
  var actionName = actions[clickCount] || defaultActionName;
  actors[actionName]();
}
```

And yes, you could just merge `actions` & `actors`. But i prefer this approach for maintenance & readability.

Comment: The asker wanted to e.g. shake the page on the 6th click, not just play different sounds.

Comment: Thanks so much; this looks amazing. I am wondering How I could implement it though; to the point of triggering, say, an MP3 file at one of the defined variables..?

Comment: @1977: I have updated the answer. Let me know, if it is not useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
// put your click actions as functions here
var clickEvents = [function1, function2, function3, function4, playMP3, shakePage];
var clicks = 0;
// put your clickable object here
clickableObject.onclick = function(){
    clickEvents[clicks]();
    clicks++;
}
```